# Macports Apache httpd not starting on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, macports, httpd

So, after 2 days of struggling to figure why Macports Apache `httpd` suddenly decided to stop working, finally it came down to this:

```
$ sudo bash -x /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
ARGV='-k start'
HTTPD=/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd
test -f /opt/local/apache2/bin/envvars
. /opt/local/apache2/bin/envvars
test x '!=' x
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
LYNX='lynx -dump'
STATUSURL=http://localhost:80/server-status
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES=
'[' x '!=' x ']'
ERROR=0
'[' 'x-k start' = x ']'
case $ARGV in
/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
ERROR=1
exit 1
```

This is the elephant in the room, does `ERROR=1` mean anything?

I ran debug and I get the same error above:

```
$ sudo bash -x /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start -e Debug -E /dev/stdout
```

Local Mac Apache returns no errors and `httpd` starts normally, it gives this output:

```
$ sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k start
ACMD=-k
ARGV='-k start'
HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd
test -f /usr/sbin/envvars
. /usr/sbin/envvars
test x '!=' x
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
LYNX='lynx -dump'
STATUSURL=http://localhost:80/server-status
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES=
LAUNCHCTL=/bin/launchctl
LAUNCHD_JOB=/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
'[' x '!=' x ']'
ERROR=0
'[' 'x-k start' = x ']'
case $ARGV in
/usr/sbin/httpd -k start
ERROR=0
exit 0
```

This is probably my last shоt at this, after 2 days I am willing to give up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered earlier on MAMP the module called `unique_id_module` was preventing it from starting. So I disabled it in `httpd.conf` and now Macports Apache starts with no errors.

Just uncomment it like this:

```
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

Answer (score 1):

ERROR=1 means that the bash script is setting the environment variable "ERROR" to the value 1.

apachectl basically does:

```
$HTTPD $ARGV
ERROR=$?

exit $ERROR
```

The issue is that `/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start` is exiting with an exit code of 1.  You should figure out why that is.  You said you ran `sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start -e Debug -E /dev/stdout` but saw no errors.  What was the exit code?

Comment: Sorry, I meant yes when I run `sudo bash -x /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start -e Debug -E /dev/stdout` I also get ERROR=1 and exit 1

Comment: Can it possible be related to the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, because if you notice in the Local Apache which runs the it doesn't use fallback `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`